# Добавление данных в таблицу с помощью AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Пытаюсь запихнуть данные в таблицу с помощью ajax, но почему-то они не добавляются.

Код:

```js
update_sensor_values();

var sensors_table = $('#sensors_view');
var info_table = $('#basic_view_table');

function update_sensor_values() {

  fetch('api')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

      console.log('data: ', data)

      let wifi_name = data.wifi_name;
      let rssi = data.rssi;
      let uptime = data.uptime;
      let battery_voltage = data.battery_voltage;
      let normal_uptime = new Date(uptime * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)

      let sensor_values = data.sensors;

      sensor_values.forEach((sensor) => {
        sensors_table.append("<tr><td>" + sensor.name + "</td><td>" + sensor.temperature + "</td><td>" + sensor.himidity + "</td>" + sensor.heat_index + "</td></tr>");
      });

      info_table.append("<tr><td>" + battery_voltage + "</td><td>" + rssi + "</td><td>" + normal_uptime + "</td><td>" + wifi_name + "</td></tr>")

      setTimeout(update_sensor_values, 2000);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('Error: ', e);
      setTimeout(update_sensor_values, 2000);
    });
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: auto;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html style="font-family: Helvetica;">

<head>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <h1 style="text-align: center;"> Умный тупой подвал v0.1 beta </h1>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="font-size:24px;">
    <table id="sensors_view">
      <tr>
        <td>Название датчика</td>
        <td>Температура</td>
        <td>Влажность</td>
        <td>По ощущениям</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div style="font-size:24px;">
    <table id="basic_view_table">
      <tr>
        <td>Заряд аккумулятора</td>
        <td>Уровень сигнала</td>
        <td>Время работы</td>
        <td>Подключен к wifi</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: что хранится в res, а что передается в data? приложите пожалуйста

Comment: @midnightelf18, уже понял проблему. Я не подключил jquery. Но проблема в том, что сайт будет на IOT ус-ве, где может и не быть доступа к интернету. Нужно как-то без jquery все это сделать. В data хранится json: {"wifi_name":"Wifi_House1","rssi":-80,"uptime":293,"battery_voltage":11.83116,"sensors":[{"name":"Уличный","temperature":20.2,"himidity":66,"heat_index":19.99869},{"name":"Внутренний потолочный","temperature":20.4375},{"name":"Внутренний напольный","temperature":20.3,"himidity":74,"heat_index":20.31757}]}

Comment: а скачать jquery и подключить локально не вариант?

Comment: @midnightelf18, память очень ограничена

Comment: просто отключите jquery вы и так его очень мало используете в своем коде. вроде только где var sensors_table = $('#sensors_view'); var info_table = $('#basic_view_table').

Comment: @midnightelf18, именно. А чем его заменить? Как добавить значения сенсоров в таблицу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

отключите jquery. он вам не нужен

```js
update_sensor_values();

var sensors_table = document.getElementById("sensors_view");
var info_table = document.getElementById("basic_view_table");

function update_sensor_values() {

  fetch('api')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {

      console.log('data: ', data)

      let wifi_name = data.wifi_name;
      let rssi = data.rssi;
      let uptime = data.uptime;
      let battery_voltage = data.battery_voltage;
      let normal_uptime = new Date(uptime * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)

      let sensor_values = data.sensors;

      sensor_values.forEach((sensor) => {
        sensors_table.append("<tr><td>" + sensor.name + "</td><td>" + sensor.temperature + "</td><td>" + sensor.himidity + "</td>" + sensor.heat_index + "</td></tr>");
      });

      info_table.append("<tr><td>" + battery_voltage + "</td><td>" + rssi + "</td><td>" + normal_uptime + "</td><td>" + wifi_name + "</td></tr>")

      setTimeout(update_sensor_values, 2000);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('Error: ', e);
      setTimeout(update_sensor_values, 2000);
    });
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: auto;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html style="font-family: Helvetica;">

<head>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <h1 style="text-align: center;"> Умный тупой подвал v0.1 beta </h1>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="font-size:24px;">
    <table id="sensors_view">
      <tr>
        <td>Название датчика</td>
        <td>Температура</td>
        <td>Влажность</td>
        <td>По ощущениям</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div style="font-size:24px;">
    <table id="basic_view_table">
      <tr>
        <td>Заряд аккумулятора</td>
        <td>Уровень сигнала</td>
        <td>Время работы</td>
        <td>Подключен к wifi</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```